# Cannot assign a default value to a local variable in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, default-value, declare

I am trying to declare local variable like:

```
DECLARE @thresholdDate DATETIME = '2014-11-30'
```

And I am getting error:

> Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.

As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx):

```
DECLARE @find varchar(30); 
/* Also allowed: 
DECLARE @find varchar(30) = 'Man%'; 
*/
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is not possible in `SQL SERVER 2005`. It is supported from `SQL SEVER 2008` and above

Comment: In your link to the docs, use the *Other Versions* drop-down at the top to select *SQL 2005* for the correct syntax.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Prior to SQL Server 2008, assigning a default value (or initial value) to a local variable is not allowed; otherwise this error message will be encountered.

**Solution 1:** (Use `SET`)

```
DECLARE @thresholdDate DATETIME 
set @thresholdDate = '2014-11-30'
```

For more details about the error : http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-139.aspx

**Solution 2:** (**Upgrade**)

Another way of avoiding this error, which is a little bit a far-fetched solution, is to upgrade to SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2008 now allows the assigning of a value to a variable in the DECLARE statement.

Comment: Have you read a question? I want default value (in-line syntax)

Comment: Have you read the error. `Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.` Which means your version of SQL does not support it. According to your link `Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Azure SQL Database.`

Comment: For that you have to buy SQL server 2012

Comment: @Jaques I kinda see that it's cannot assign, but that still doesn't explains anything. Mention of that earlier versions doesn't support that makes sense.

Comment: @Veera gave you the correct answer, because SQL Server 2005 doesn't support that syntax sugar (in-line syntax)

Answer (score 6):

You will hit this error

> Cannot assign a default value to a local variable

in case you are running SQL Server 2005 or earlier, and you try to declare a variable and assign it a value in one statement.

Something like  -

```
DECLARE @Var Varchar(15) = 'Test'
```

> Message 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
>   Cannot assign a default value to a local variable

Variable declaration has been enhanced in SQL Server 2008 and newer versions, and I realized this today when I was deploying a code for multiple systems.

[image]

Apparently we also have the flexibility to just use one Declare statement to declare multiple variables  -

```
DECLARE @Var Varchar(15) = 'Test',
        @Char Varchar(10) = 'Test2',
        @Char2 Varchar(10) = 'Test3'
```

In SQL Server 2005 or earlier, you will need to declare the variable and then assign it a value using Set statement.

Example -

```
DECLARE @Var Varchar(15) 
SET @Var = 'Test'
```

Answer (score 2):

The error

> Cannot assign a default value to a local variable

occurs if you are using **SQL Server 2005** while assigning `default value` to `local variable`.

For **SQL Server 2005** use this code:

```
DECLARE @thresholdDate AS DATETIME 

SET @thresholdDate = '2014-11-30'

SELECT @thresholdDate
```

For **SQL Server 2008 and newer** you can use this instead:

```
DECLARE @thresholdDate DATETIME = '2014-11-30'
SELECT @thresholdDate
```

Comment: `DECLARE @thresholdDate DATETIME = '2014-11-30'` will work in `SQL SERVER 2008`+..

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SomeVariable AS DATETIME
SET @SomeVariable = '2014-11-30';

//Or if some one like to get last affected record id
DECLARE @SomeVariable AS VARCHAR(100);
SET @SomeVariable = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID);
```