# Searching date between two given Dates

Tags: sql-server

I have two specific dates.
lets say from 2014-04-04 To 2015-10-04.
I have a plan that says classes of Blah course will be on mon, wed and Fri.
Now I want to get the dates of each mon, wed and Fri from 2014-04-04 to 2015-10-04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Recursive CTE if you do not have numbers table. Something like this. Note that the `DATEPART(weekday,Dates) IN(1,3,5)` is based on your setting of `SELECT @@DATEFIRST`.

For example If `@@DATEFIRST` is `1` then use `DATEPART(weekday,Dates) IN(1,3,5)`

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2014-04-04'
SET @EndDate = '2015-10-04'
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate Dates
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(d,1,Dates) FROM CTE WHERE DATEADD(d,1,Dates) <=@EndDate
)

SELECT Dates,DATENAME(weekday,Dates) FROM CTE
WHERE DATEPART(weekday,Dates) IN(1,3,5)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
GO
```

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@EndDate".

Comment: Thats weird, sql server 2008 supports `date` datatype. try changing it to `DATETIME`

Comment: m using 2005
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@EndDate".

Comment: @ughai we've now confirmed it's SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 6
Must declare the scalar variable "@StartDate".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@EndDate".

Comment: are you trying the update answer which has `datetime`?

Comment: My bad. SQL Server 2005 [doesn't support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060586/cannot-assign-a-default-value-to-a-local-variable-in-sql) assigning of values in `DECLARE`. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

With a calendar  table it is simple:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.TableName t
INNER JOIN CalendarTable c 
    ON t.DateColumn = c.Date
WHERE c.Date between '2014-04-04' AND '2015-10-04'
AND DATEPART(dw, c.Date) IN (1,3,5)
```

[How to generate a calendar table](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) (look for "Calendar table").

Comment: I dont have a date table.
just a batch table which has a column of Date from and a column of Date to

Comment: @Shafay:  a good time to create one?! As mentioned in the article, 30 years dates are just 136KB hard drive space.

Comment: @TimSchmelter See? Scoffed as usual!

Comment: My task doesn't said to do something like creating a new table.
but ya i can use a userdefined table . if u can help me with that then that'll be great

Comment: @Shafay: it's all explained very well in the articel linked in my answer. Maybe you need to start with [Part1](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) instead of [Part3](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) since generating the calendar-table involves techniques used to generate number sequences.

Answer (score 2):

The standard reply to this by any seasoned SQL Server veteran, would be to create a calendar table. But all too often this is scoffed. So here's a *slow* and out-of-the-box method:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2014-04-04', @endDate DATE = '2015-10-04';

WITH CTE(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))a(N)),
CTE2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE x CROSS JOIN CTE y),
CTE3(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE2 x CROSS JOIN CTE2 y),
CTE4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE3 x CROSS JOIN CTE3 y),
CTE5(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE4 x CROSS JOIN CTE4 y),
CTE6(N) AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(day,@startDate,@endDate)) 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
            FROM CTE5),
TALLY(N) AS (SELECT DATEADD(day, N, @startDate)
             FROM CTE6
             WHERE DATENAME(weekday,DATEADD(day, N, @startDate)) IN ('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'))
SELECT N
FROM TALLY
ORDER BY N;
```

Comment: Can you please Define this.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. What do you mean by 'define'?

Comment: Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 12
Must declare the scalar variable "@startDate".

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're running 2005 if you're getting these error messages. Can you run `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2014-04-04'
SET @EndDate = '2015-10-04'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate Dates
    UNION ALL SELECT DATEADD(d,1,Dates) FROM CTE WHERE DATEADD(d,1,Dates) <=@EndDate
)

SELECT Dates,DATENAME(weekday,Dates) FROM CTE
WHERE DATEPART(weekday,Dates) IN(1,3,5)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
GO

--- thanks to @ughai

Comment: you don't need to re-answer. if an answer helped you, you only need to mark an answer as accepted . you can up vote all answers which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I've comeup with another way to do this.
this query will not only Show the dates in between but also it will compare the dates u want to compare with.

Q.Dates Comparison

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2014-12-22'
SET @EndDate = '2015-02-13'

drop table #TabCourseDetailID
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CourseDetailID asc) AS Row,
             CourseDetailID 
 into #TabCourseDetailID
 from coursedetail 
 where UnitType='T' and courseID =1

Declare @counter as int 
 Declare @CourseDetailID varchar(500)
 set @counter = 0

Declare @TempTable Table  (FirstValue datetime,LastValue  int)

while @StartDate <= @EndDate
    begin 
         If DATEPART(WeekDay,@StartDate) IN (2,4,6)
             begin

```
            Set @Counter = @counter+1 

            Select @CoursedetailId=CoursedetailId 
                from #TabCourseDetailID 
            where row=@counter

            insert into @TempTable (FirstValue,LastValue) 
            values                 (@StartDate,@CoursedetailId)

         end 
set @StartDate =DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate)
end 




select t.LastValue,
        t.FirstValue,
        bp.conductedDate  
from batchprogress bp
Join @TempTable t on (t.LastValue=bp.CoursedetailID)
where CourseID =1 and batchID =5
order by  t.lastvalue
```